# Another nested loop in R

Tags: r

I have the following data and nested for loop:

```
x <- c(12, 27, 21, 16, 12, 21, 18, 16, 20, 23, 21, 10, 15, 26, 21, 22, 22, 19, 26, 26)
y <- c(8, 10,  7,  7,  9,  5,  7,  7, 10,  4, 10,  3,  9,  6,  4,  2,  4,  2,  3,  6)

a <- c(20,25) 
a.sub <- c()
df <- c()
for(j in 1:length(a)){
    a.sub <- which(x >= a[j])   
    for(i in 1:length(a.sub)){
        df[i] <- y[a.sub[i]]    
    }
    print(df)
}
```

I'd like the loop to return values for df as:

```
[1] 10  6  3  6  4 10  6  4  2  4  3  6
[1] 10  6  3  6
```

As I have it, however, the loop returns the same values twice of df for a <- 20 but not a <- 25:

```
[1] 10  7  5 10  4 10  6  4  2  4  3  6
[1] 10  6  3  6  4 10  6  4  2  4  3  6
```

Comment: `error in which(p >= a[j]): object 'p' not found`

Comment: and maybe explain what it is you are trying to do in english, nested loops in R can often be rewritten using other, more efficient constructs

Comment: John's answer below works well.  I'm looking to form `df` from elements of `y` that have corresponding `x` values less than `a`.

Comment: Was the order of your first output important?  You seem to have reordered it selecting items greater than 25 first and then appending greater than 20 but less than 25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(i in 1:length(a.sub)){
    df[i] <- y[a.sub[i]]    
}
```

can become

```
df <- y[a.sub]
```

neither a.sub nor df need to be predefined then and thus...

```
x <- c(12, 27, 21, 16, 12, 21, 18, 16, 20, 23, 21, 10, 15, 26, 21, 22, 22, 19, 26, 26)
y <- c(8, 10,  7,  7,  9,  5,  7,  7, 10,  4, 10,  3,  9,  6,  4,  2,  4,  2,  3,  6)

a <- c(20,25) 
for(j in 1:length(a)){
    a.sub <- which(x >= a[j])   
    df <- y[a.sub]    
    print(df)
}
```

It could be made shorter. df is unnecessary if you're just printing the subset of y anyway.  Just print it directly.  And the selector is so short it wouldn't make a single line confusing.  Furthermore, why use length of a and index.. loop through a directly.  So, it could be...

```
a <- c(20,25) 
for(ax in a){
    print( y[ which(x >= ax) ] )
}
```

Comment: But I do not think that returns:  [1] 10  6  3  6  4 10  6  4  2  4  3  6

Comment: I agree.. but it simplifies his code and replicates what that actually did... maybe he can make it do what the heck he was looking for now that it's easier. :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a simplified version of a more complex problem, but I'd probably solve this using some direct indexing and an apply  function. Something like this:

```
z <- cbind(x,y)
sapply(c(20,25), function(x) z[z[, 1] >= x, 2])
[[1]]
 [1] 10  7  5 10  4 10  6  4  2  4  3  6

[[2]]
[1] 10  6  3  6
```

Comment: Somehow the original poster wants:  10  6  3  6  4 10  6  4  2  4  3  6 the first time through the second loop.

Comment: why bother with cbind?  They can just be treated as separate vectors.

Comment: @John - good point, habit of creature I suppose? I have this (irrational) fear of the order of objects getting out of whack if they're completely separate entities, or getting corrupted by some other command in my workspace...I would also probably run `rm(x,y)` after creating `z` so as to not confuse myself too...but it's probably overkill and not necessary as you point out.